# ORA-03113 - end of communication channel

Tags: sql, oracle, select, database-performance, sql-tuning

I have a select query has joined with four tables. All the tables has index column which are used in where clause. This query which return top ten records from around 5000 to 6000 records. In my local database this query has return the record in few seconds, but in the server it takes long time and didn't return any record instead a error is popping message box that ORA-03113: end of file on communication channel.

Actually there is another team, shared that query to me. That team can able to fetch the data from the server, but my query can't since both query were same. The difference between my query and their has same difference. I'm using round off function to round off the value, but they are not using in the query instead they handling in the front end. So they asked me to remove the round off function and try. i removed the round off function and tried. Still the loading and shows ora error end of communication channel.

My query look like this

```
SELECT *FROM (SELECT col1,
       col2,
       CASE WHEN col3 = 'A' THEN col4 CASE WHEN col5 = 'B' THEN col4 ELSE NULL END alias1,
       CASE WHEN col3 = 'A' THEN col6 CASE WHEN col5 = 'A' THEN col6 ELSE NULL END alias2,
       col7,
       col8,
       col9,
       to_char(dense_rank()
           over(ORDER
            BY(t2.col17 marketnav(t3.col20,
                 to_date('01-JAN-1940', 'dd-mon-yyyy'),
                 to_date(t1.col20, 'dd-mon-yyyy'))) DESC)) in_rank,
       funct1(col10, col11, col12),
       col13,
       col14,
       funct1(col10, col11, col12)
  FROM t1,
       t2,
       t3,
       t4
 WHERE t1.col15 = t2.col15 AND
       t1.col12 = t1.col12 AND
       t1.col20 = t3.col20 AND
       t1.col21 = t4.col21 AND
       t2.date1 IS NOT NULL AND
       trunc(t2.date1) = '16-Jun-2020') WHERE in_rank < 11
```

I can run and fetch data in local database, but in the server it takes time and didn't return
 any record. What is the problem?
Note:My local database may be less satisfied data compare to server database.

Comment: please run an explain plan on the problem query on the remote db and show the results. Through what client are you executing the query?

Comment: ORA-03113 is a very generic error. It signifies that something broke your connection to the database (like a network outage), or that your database session crashed unexpectedly. Check the database server for any related trace files for your session to determine if there's a system resource issue or a bug involved in your situation. Don't assume that your query is necessarily the problem just yet.

Comment: Why are you choosing to use archaic join syntax rather than proper, explicit, **standard** readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: I agree with @pmdba that you need to check system for error details. There should be information in the alert log, supplemented by a trace file. This is a conversation you should be having with your DBA.

Comment: Also, what is the difference between the environment used by the team who says the query works and yours? Are you in the same office? On the same network? Connecting through firewalls?

Comment: However, there is one obvious warning flag: your DENSE_RANK statement calls a udf `marketnav()` in its ORDER BY clause. That will be executed for every row in the inner query, so that's one thing to look at. Of course `funct1()` could also be problematic. But it could be something else entirely. Basically, this is not a question we can answer because it requires a lot of debugging which we cannot undertake remotely.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - The Seeker tells us they were given the query by another team. So why have a go at *them* for the syntax choices?